# Firebase API initialization failure,java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, firebase, android-appcompat, android-multidex

I am using firebase auth, database and storage services in my app. It was working fine previously. I have added firebase cloud messaging setup as described in docs. But app crashes at runtime.I investigated the issue for about 4 hours and tried different solutions. Like keeping all libs version same, changing appcompat library version and change app to multidex.But nothing helped. Below is my gradle dependencies:

```
compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

//Firebase
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
```

On compiling app produces following exception:

```
05-02 20:05:55.746 31927-31927/com.apponative.committeeapp A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627)
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5015)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4589)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzc.<init>
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbiu.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjc.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzb(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkg.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzd(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzc(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656) 
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627) 
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5015) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4589) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-02 20:05:55.774 31927-31927/com.apponative.committeeapp A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627)
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5015)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4589)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzx.getNoBackupFilesDir
      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzh.zzeG(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzh.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzh.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656) 
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627) 
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5015) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4589) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-02 20:05:55.818 31927-31927/com.apponative.committeeapp A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627)
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5015)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4589)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapn.zzb
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656) 
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627) 
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5015) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4589) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-02 20:05:55.845 31927-31927/com.apponative.committeeapp A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656)  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627)   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5015)  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4589)at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzatp at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656)  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627)  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5015)  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4589)  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-02 20:05:56.468 31927-31927/com.apponative.committeeapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
05-02 20:05:56.842 31927-31927/com.apponative.committeeapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.apponative.committeeapp, PID: 31927
     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzc.<init>       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbiu.<init>(Unknown Source)                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjc.zza(Unknown Source)                  at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzb(Unknown Source)                 at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(Unknown Source)               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkg.<init>(Unknown Source)               at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzd(Unknown Source)                   at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzc(Unknown Source)                  at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)               at com.apponative.committeeapp.firebase.FireBaseAuth.fireBaseAuth(FireBaseAuth.java:42)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not include `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1` as a dependency.  This adds ALL the Google Play Services APIs to your build and will probably require you to use MultiDex.  Instead, follow the directions provided in the [Setup Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) in the section titled *Selectively compiling APIs into your executable* to add as depencies *only* the specific APIs that you actually use.

Also, the version of the Firebase UI libraries that you include must be compatible with the version of Firebase libraries.  The table of compatible versions is include in the [Firebase UI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries). For Firebase APIs version 10.0.1, you should use `firebase-ui-storage:1.1.1`

Comment: I tried your suggestions but no success, issue is still same

Comment: @SairaNawaz Update your question then. Because Firebase UI v0.6.0 is NOT compatible with Firebase 10.x.x. We need to know that's not the issue. And DO remove the `play-services` dependency. Important parts are added automatically. Clean build after that.

Comment: @EugenPechanec thanx , issue is solved now, i had to remove messaging api ,and after cleaning ,rebuilding Bob 's suggestions worked