# How to fix "Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin"

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3. I tried use Firebase RealTime Authentication in my app and I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.0.

My project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ccnstudent.hridoychandradas.ccnapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Follow the example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44508542/4815718 with `SUPPORT_LIB_VER = '25.4.0'` and `GOOGLE_LIB_VER = '11.0.2'`.  Also, you should not include all of Play Services with this: `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2`.  Better to include only the APIs you need.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43743746/4815718

Answer (score 0):

I think  you should check the spelling of your google-services.json file.if not Right click on the file choose refactor -> to google-services.json

Comment: compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0"

Comment: 11.0.2 not 9.2.0